# ISO8601DateFormatter accepts wrong input

Tags: swift

I want to parse a date of the format `yyyyMM` to a date (e.g. 202007 should convert to July 2020). This works fine using DateFormatter - also when sending wrongly formatted input to it:

```
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMM"
   let result = formatter.date(from: "***")// = nil
```

But after reading Apple's [documentation for DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter), I tried changing to ISO8601DateFormatter instead due to this phrase:

> When working with date representations in ISO 8601 format, use
> ISO8601DateFormatter instead.

However, I cannot make it work properly when sending invalid input to it:

```
   let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
   formatter.formatOptions = [.withMonth, .withYear]
   let result = formatter.date(from: "***")//= 2000-01-01 00:00:00
```

Why does `formatter.date` return a date an not nil when sending a wrongly formatted string to it? Are there any way to make to above code return nil instead?

Comment: You also might check that `formatter.string(from: Date())` returns "202007", with no "-", so it might no be what you expect. It's missing `withDashSeparatorInDate` in the option, and then it return `nil` as expected. Why it was not returning nil without that specification, it's unclear though. Default behavior (strange one) because of `formatOptions` "invalid"?

Comment: @Larme You are right - if adding `withDashSeparatorInDate`, I will get nil. I didn't notice that option, and now I am annoyed at myself that I inserted that - because I actually also need it to work without the DashSeparator. I will update my question according to this, since you have given a solution for the problem where I have a dash. And yes - that may just be a very strange default behavior

Comment: Side note: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates , `yyyyMM` isn't valid. I'd say it's a bug for Apple having an invalid format, and returning not nil.

Comment: You got me. That is exactly why I added the dash for the question :-D - but it does not seem that Apple knows that since leaving the `withDashSeparatorInDate` out generates dates without dashes, as you wrote in your first comment.
I think you are right - probably just a bug, meaning that `ISO8601DateFormatter` only works properly if specifying `withDashSeparatorInDate`

Comment: By the way: It is not related to an invalid format. The error is the same if you add `.withDay` (equivalent to `yyyyMMdd`), and that is an allowed format. So I think I will report this as a bug to Apple.